# Expanding a home network with WiFi + Switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, ethernet, switch

So I’ll be moving into a student house soon that comes with Virgin internet, however, my room is at the other end of the house to where the router is, which means the WiFi signal is not very strong.

My plan was to run an Ethernet cable from the router to my room, where I can then have wired connections using a switch and then have the WiFi network expanded to properly reach my room.

My question then is, do I connect the Ethernet cable to the switch and then an access point to the switch? If that’s the case, does anyone have any recommendations for a switch and good access point that can mesh the new network with the original so I do not have to switch between networks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> any recommendations for a switch and good access point that can mesh the new network with the original so I do not have to switch between networks?

Literally any switch and any access point will work, as long as you configure the AP with the same SSID and security mode as your main network. (The channels do not need to match; indeed they *should* be different.)

Of course, first make sure that you *have* the same network accessible through both access points (i.e. same subnet all over, no routers with NAT in-between), otherwise your client devices can get very confused.

Specific recommendations for "good" products are somewhat out of scope for this place.

Note that each device makes its own decision about when it's time to jump to a new AP (i.e. iOS and Android will behave slightly differently). Some of them will try to stick to a weak 5 GHz signal even if a nearby 2.4 GHz one is available, so keep that in mind before buying a cheap 2.4-only AP.

Basic roaming does not require any special support from the AP side.  There *are* various access points with "improved" roaming (supporting 802.11r, etc), but usually these features only work between the same kind of AP, and often only between controller-managed APs (or "mesh AP" nodes, etc).